# Nginx + Wordpress language redirect

Tags: nginx, redirect, language

i am currently trying to configure an Nginx installation with Wordpress multisite used for language support.

The multisite is configured:
mysite.com (not used)
mysite.com/it
mysite.com/en

Basically i want to add a default language and redirect if i find english. The site is actually on an Apache installation so we use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /en/ [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^$ /it/ [L,R=301]
```

for the actual redirect.

I'm trying to replicate that with nginx, without any luck. So far i added:

```
map $http_accept_language $lang {
    default it;
    ~en en;
}

server {

 listen       80;
 server_name  mysite.com;
 access_log  /var/log/nginx/logs/mysite-access.log ;
 error_log /var/log/nginx/logs/mysite-error.log ;

 location / {
    root   /var/www/html/mysite;
    index  index.php index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    rewrite ^ /$lang/ permanent;
 }    

#Other rules used by wordpress and plugins
}
```

This results in "The page does not redirect correctly" error.

Any tips on how to solve the issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/accept_language/ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a problem:

```
    rewrite ^ /$lang/ permanent;
```

You are rewriting *every* request, not merely requests to the home page, because *every* request has a beginning.

There are (at least) two ways to fix this. You can use either:

1. Rewrite only requests for the home page.

   ```
   rewrite ^/$ /$lang/ permanent;
   ```
2. Use a specific `location` that matches only the home page:

   ```
   location = / {
       return 301 /$lang/;
   }
   ```