# Nginx + Wordpress language redirect wrong with default language

Tags: nginx, redirect, wordpress

Nginx + Wordpress language redirect wrong with default language

Sorry for duplicate this questions here:
[Nginx + Wordpress language redirect](https://serverfault.com/questions/775613/nginx-wordpress-language-redirect)

All works but for the default EN language.

I just want to redirect JP visitors to /ja/ directory, maybe more other countries to other directories later.

For now, I want all other countries to the root domain.

The rule I used is:

```
map $http_accept_language $lang {
    default en;
    ~ja ja;
}

...

rewrite ^/$ /$lang/ permanent;
```

This rule redirected all other visitors to mydomain.com/en/, that's 404 of course since EN is my main language!

=======================================

This is all the rules in the site side config

Hope anyone can help me with this !

```
map $http_accept_language $lang {
default en;
~ja ja;
}

server 
{ 
listen 80; 
listen 443 ssl http2; 
server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com; 
index index.php index.html index.htm default.php default.htm default.html; 
root /www/wwwroot/mydomain.com;

#REWRITE-START

rewrite ^/$ /$lang/ permanent;

include /www/server/panel/vhost/rewrite/mydomain.com.conf;
#REWRITE-END


location ~ ^/(\.user.ini|\.htaccess|\.git|\.svn|\.project|LICENSE|README.md)
{
    return 404;
}


location ~ \.well-known{
    allow all;
}

location ~ .*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|swf)$
{
    expires      30d;
    error_log /dev/null;
    access_log /dev/null;
}

location ~ .*\.(js|css)?$
{
    expires      12h;
    error_log /dev/null;
    access_log /dev/null; 
}
access_log  /www/wwwlogs/mydomain.com.log;
error_log  /www/wwwlogs/mydomain.com.log;
}
```

Comment: You have `default en;` in your map - are you saying that you don't want the default to redirect to `/en/`?

Comment: yes, @Richard Smith，  just want to redirect translated language to their directories,  all others to root:  mydomian.com

Comment: Hi @Richard Smith ， thanks for your reply, but sorry since I don't know how to code, so would you please help me with the   ` if ($lang) { ... }`

Comment: I  just post my whole side wide config file below, please help me check it

Comment: sorry my mistake, just deleted the reply and edited the question!

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault. Your rewrite statement could be written like `if ( $lang != "en" ) { rewrite ^/$ /$lang/ permanent; }` in order to achieve the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `default en;` line from your `map`, the value of `$lang` will become the empty string which is evaluated as false in an `if` expression. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for details.

You can replace the `rewrite ^/$ ...` statement with a `location = /` block. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

For example:

```
map $http_accept_language $lang {
    ~ja ja;
}

server {
    ...
    location = / {
        if ($lang) {
            return 301 /$lang/$is_args$args;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

See [this document](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on which statements are permitted within an `if` block that's nested within a `location` block.

Comment: That works but another problem comes:  for other language, it redrected to   mydomain.com//    , there are 2 "//" in the end